# Show that zero attractor basin is not $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have a dynamical system
$$
   \left\{
   \begin{array}{rcl}
   \dot {x_1} & = & -\frac{2x_{1}}{(1+x_{1}^2)^2} - \frac{2x_2}{(1+x_2^2)^2} \\
   \dot {x_2} & = & 2x_1 - \frac{2 x_2}{(1+x_2^2)^2}
   \end{array}
   \right.
$$
Here $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Zero solution is an attractor, but I know that zero solution is not a global attractor. How to show this analitically (without writing a program)? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why is it not a global attractor? How do you know that?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis I wrote a program. Furthermore, it is a homework problem!